# Jquery datepicker - missing 28. of january 2015

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

idk why but datepicker do not show me 28. of January 2015.

Any ideas why?

I am using jQuery UI - v1.11.2

Thanks

[image]

Comment: can you show the Screenshot of of your datepicker?

Comment: That's today, and [you can see from their demo](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) that they highlight the current day. Any chance your 'current day' style is 'hide', or blended into the background? Can you inspect the calendar control to see if it's actually there but just hidden or oddly styled? Is your control set up to choose past dates only? If you change your PC date to tomorrow does it then appear?

Comment: @Rup thanks. You are right it is a problem with styles.

Comment: You said Jan but the Screenshots looks like Feb . Remove the current theme and check with Default theme.